# Get year-to-date gain in percentage in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I would like to get the year-to-date gain of a Trading View chart using pine-script. The gain is to be expressed in percentage.

I am using pine-script v5.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the number of bars that have passed year-to-date. From there, calculate the year-to-date gain.

```
get_yeartodate_gain_percentage() =>
    int num_bars_ytd = 0 //number of bars passed year to date
    num_bars_ytd := ta.barssince(ta.change(time("12M")))
    float ytd_gain_pct = 0    
    ytd_gain_pct := (close[0] - close[num_bars_ytd+1])/close[num_bars_ytd+1]*100
    ytd_gain_pct
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I can think of, is getting the number of bars past since the beginning of the year (the first bar the year changed), and than use the historical reference of `strategy.equity` in order to get the equity for the beginning of the year.
From there it's just comparing the current equity and the beginning of the year equity and use simple math to calculate as percentage:

```
barsSinceBeginingOfYear = ta.barssince(ta.change(time("12M")))
equityBeginingOfYear = strategy.equity[barsSinceBeginingOfYear]

profitTTD = ((strategy.equity / equityBeginingOfYear) - 1) * 100
```

Comment: Thanks but the code cannot compile.

Comment: Weird. Works great here. Of course you need to add the full strategy and decide how to show the results (usually a label or a table), but other than that it should work